# Viewing the Graphical Layout Landscape Android

Tags: android, landscape

I have been trying to develop an application in a landscape mode so I placed "android: screenOrientation="landscape" in my Manifest. It worked well, however, the graphical layout of my xml files are still not in landscape mode so I cannot design my UI well. Any help? Thanks

Comment: You are talking about layout in emulator or in eclipse editor?

Comment: layout in the emulator in already landscaped.. however, the eclipse editor in graphical layout of my xml is still in vertical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that, Then mark it as correct so that others may find it useful by clicking on tick on left side

Comment: by the way, @ingsaurabh, how can i insert image here just like what you did above to show the screen shot?

Comment: There is a mark of pic when u post an answer or question choose that and follow the procedure

Answer (score 0):

you should design separate UI for landscape mode and put in layout-land folder. check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

go to res folder in your project, and create a new folder in it name it as `layout-land`

Comment: how would I create that folder? sorry i am very beginner here