# can we rotate emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rotate the Android emulator display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display)

I have created an emulator 1024x600. api level 9. Problem is my application has a portrait  view. It can not be viewed as landscape.

so I want to view it as 600x1024 view. Therefore, is there anyway to solve this? I think you understand me.

Comment: Ctrl + F12

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535298/how-to-rotate-the-android-emulator-display

Comment: thanks . I thougt this is a dumb question to ask.

Comment: @kiriappa It is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Also see [Keyboard Commands for Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Here is a link for shortcuts [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057309/1503155)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>F11</kbd>

**or**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +<kbd>12</kbd>  on windows.

While we are at it here are other shortcuts [answer](https://shortcutworld.com/Android-SDK-Emulator/win/Android-Emulator_Shortcuts) . 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows :** use left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>F12</kbd>  to switch between landscape and portrait modes.

**Mac use :** <kbd>Fn</kbd>  + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

**Windows:** <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

**OS X:**  <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

You can also change between Landscape and Portrait in Eclipse, using the Graphical Layout of the View.

***See below:***

[image]
[Viewing the Graphical Layout Landscape Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978931/viewing-the-graphical-layout-landscape-android)

Answer (score 1):

**Two Shortcuts:-**

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- **NumLock** <kbd>Off</kbd> , then<kbd>press</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd> key from the side Keyboard.